# Can anyone identify these flowers?

Tags: botany, flowers

[image]

I'm mostly interested in the maroon and white ones in the center, or the purple and white ones in the front left corner.  They were in bloom in a garden in July at the Buffalo Harbor.  Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Given that these are garden plants it might be worth searching on [SE Gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com). If you can't find an answer there you could pose the question there. Also, you need to provide more information about the location.

Comment: They look like petunias to me, but this is far from my area of expertise

Answer (score 6):

[image]

The sign agrees. They are petunias. The specific variety of the red ones is raspberry swirl. I don't know the specific variety of the purple ones.

Comment: Yea I saw the sign after I'd posted, but couldn't see an option to delete the post

Comment: @BeckieMaryland no worries! It was a little hard to spot. I didn't post it to shame you or anything, just to provide evidence for my answer :)

Comment: @BeckieMaryland take a look at the help for [someone answers](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you feel like this answers your question, you can accept it by clicking the gray checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

The violet ones are called Violet Star Charm Petunias and the maroon ones are maybe Madness Burgundy or Easy Wave Burgundy.